# in __getattr__ raise AttributeError(name) AttributeError: shape

Tags: numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, shapes

I'm creating tissue masks for a bunch of pathology images and in one of the steps for preparing them ı had to change the black pixels to white.
my code works for one image but when I want to apply it to image file in a directory I received this error :

I don't understand the error and don't know to solve it.

```
File "/Users/sepideh/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-.../My Drive/Remove_empty_pixels/Remove_empty_pixels.py", line 108, in <module>
    height, width, _ = img.shape
  File "/Users/sepideh/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 529, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: shape
```

```
   and this is my code :
```

```
        height, width, _ = img.shape
        white_px = np.asarray([255, 255, 255])
        black_px = np.asarray([0  , 0  , 0  ])
        img2 = np.array(img, copy=True)

        for i in range(height):
            for j in range(width):
                px = img[i][j]
                if all(px == black_px):
                    img2[i][j] = white_px
```

I want to understand the reason for this error and a solution for it.

Comment: It means that the object that is stored in your variable `img` does not have an attribute called `shape`, but yet you're calling it: `img.shape`. Perhaps the object is not the type that you think it is. Can you add `print(type(img))` before the first line of your code to check the type?

Comment: @physicalattraction Looks like `img` is a PIL `Image`, and OP is treating it as if it was a numpy array.

Comment: Please ensure your code is [mcve] before posting.

Comment: Thank you all. as you mentioned it was because of the type of them.